# HTML element hides D3.js SVG

Tags: html, css, d3.js

**>> Problem:** The Code below contain 3 nodes with an working `on("click", function()){}`. If clicked a modal window appear. But the modal window is not drawn top of the SVG, instead the SVG area is pushed to the bottom. Further if a node is dragged to the top, it disappear behind the section background.

If I create, in the HTML body, the SVG first, I can´t click any button or even use the selection. This problem could be solved by adding `pointer-events: none` to the canvas. But this brings other problems.

Any idea, how I could solve this chicken and egg problem?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>D3v6 Shadow</title>
    <!-- call external d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
    body {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #f2f3f7;
        margin: 0px;
        color: #7b7e8c
    }

    section {
        word-wrap: break-word;
        word-break: normal;
        width: 95%;
        max-width: 350px;
        margin: 40px auto;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    hr {
        color: white;
        height: 3px;
    }

    h5 {
        margin: 0.5em;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        line-height: 1em;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    label {
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    button,
    select {
        box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -6px -6px 10px white;
        background: #f2f3f7;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 8em;
        font-size: 1rem;
        transition-property: background-color, box-shadow;
        transition-duration: .2s;
        color: #7b7e8c;
    }

    #modal-link-close {
        box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -6px -6px 10px white;
        background: #f2f3f7;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 8em;
        font-size: 1rem;
        transition-property: background-color, box-shadow;
        transition-duration: .2s;
        color: #7b7e8c;
    }

    #modal-link-close:active {
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 transparent, 0 0 transparent, inset 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset -3px -3px 5px white;
        background: #f8f9fb;

        transition-duration: .1s;
    }

    button:active,
    select {
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 transparent, 0 0 transparent, inset 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset -3px -3px 5px white;
        background: #f8f9fb;
        transition-duration: .1s;
    }

    select {
        appearance: none;
        background: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: right;
        background-size: 1.8em;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding-right: 3em;
    }

    .lightgreen {
        color: lightgreen;
    }

    .red {
        color: red
    }

    .border-round {
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .box-shadow {
        box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -6px -6px 10px white;
    }

    .modal {
        padding: 10px 20px 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        min-height: 100px;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        background: #f2f3f7;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    .canvas {
        position: absolute;
    }

    .node {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .node:hover {
        stroke: red
    }

    .link {
        fill: none;
        cursor: default;
        stroke: red;
        stroke-width: 3px;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <section id="modal-link" class="modal box-shadow">
        <h5 style="text-align:center">Relationship</h5>
        <hr class="border-round">
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <label id="details-link-source">Source --- </label>
            <select id="details-link-type-selection">
                <option>option 1</option>
                <option>option 2</option>
            </select>
            <label id="details-link-target"> --- Target</label>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <button id="modal-link-save" class="border-round"><i class="fas fa-check-circle lightgreen"></i>
                Save</button>
            <button id="modal-link-close" class="border-round"><i class="fas fa-times-circle red"></i>
                Close</button></button>
        </div>
    </section>

    <svg id="svg"> </svg>

    <script>
        var graph = {
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                }
            ],
            "links": [
                {
                    "source": 1,
                    "target": 0,
                },
                {
                    "source": 2,
                    "target": 0,
                },
            ]
        }

        var width = window.innerWidth
        var height = window.innerHeight
        var isVisible = false;

        var svg = d3.select("svg")
            .attr("class", "canvas")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
                svg.attr("transform", event.transform)
            }))
            .append("g")

        var modalLinkWindow = document.getElementById("modal-link")
        modalLinkWindow.style.display = "none"


        // remove zoom on dblclick listener
        d3.select("svg").on("dblclick.zoom", null)

        var linkContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "linkContainer")
        var nodeContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodeContainer")

        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
                return d.id;
            }).distance(150))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-50))
            .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
            .force("collision", d3.forceCollide().radius(30))


        //###############################################
        //############## Initialization #################
        //###############################################

        initialize()

        function initialize() {

            link = linkContainer.selectAll(".link")
                .data(graph.links)
                .join("line")
                .attr("class", "link")

            var grads = svg.append("defs").selectAll("radialGradient")
                .data(graph.nodes)
                .join("radialGradient")
                .attr("gradientUnits", "objectBoundingBox")
                .attr("cx", 0)
                .attr("cy", 0)
                .attr("r", "100%")
                .attr("id", function (d, i) { return "grad" + i; });

            grads.append("stop")
                .attr("offset", "80%")
                .style("stop-color", "whitesmoke");

            grads.append("stop")
                .attr("offset", "100%")
                .style("stop-color", "darkgrey");

            node = nodeContainer.selectAll(".node")
                .data(graph.nodes, d => d.id)
                .join("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragStarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragEnded)
                )
                .on("click", function () {
                    if (!isVisible) {
                        modalLinkWindow.style.display = "block"
                        isVisible = true
                    } else {
                        modalLinkWindow.style.display = "none"
                        isVisible = false
                    }
                })

            node.selectAll("circle")
                .data(d => [d])
                .join("circle")
                .attr("r", 30)
                //.style("fill", "white")
                .style("fill", function (d, i) {
                    return "url(#grad" + i + ")"
                })

            node.selectAll("text")
                .data(d => [d])
                .join("text")
                .style("class", "icon")
                .attr("font-family", "FontAwesome")
                .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("font-size", 30)
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .attr("stroke-width", "0px")
                .attr("pointer-events", "none")
                .text((d) => {
                    return d.id
                })

            simulation
                .nodes(graph.nodes)
                .on("tick", ticked);

            simulation
                .force("link")
                .links(graph.links)
        }


        //###############################################
        //############# Update Positions ################
        //###############################################

        function ticked() {
            // update link positions
            link
                .attr("x1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.x;
                })
                .attr("y1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.y;
                })
                .attr("x2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.x;
                })
                .attr("y2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.y;
                });

            // update node positions
            node
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";
                });
        }

        //###############################################
        //################ Drag Nodes ###################
        //###############################################

        function dragStarted(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;
        }

        function dragged(event, d) {
            d.fx = event.x;
            d.fy = event.y;
        }

        function dragEnded(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
            d.fx = undefined;
            d.fy = undefined;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can use css z-index property to bring a layer to the top or bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems to fix in order to achieve what you want:

1. If you want the modal to stop pushing the content down you need to replace `position: relative` with `position: absolute` and center it using `left: 0` and `right: 0`
2. `Further if a node is dragged to the top, it disappear behind the section background.` It is not disappearing behind, the issue is the `SVG` width, remove the width declaration from the js and use `width="100%"` directly in the svg element
3. In order for the chart to stay behind it just needs a `z-index` < than the modal

This should work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>D3v6 Shadow</title>
    <!-- call external d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
    body {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #f2f3f7;
        margin: 0px;
        color: #7b7e8c
    }

    section {
        word-wrap: break-word;
        word-break: normal;
        width: 95%;
        max-width: 350px;
        margin: 40px auto;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    hr {
        color: white;
        height: 3px;
    }

    h5 {
        margin: 0.5em;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        line-height: 1em;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    label {
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    button,
    select {
        box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -6px -6px 10px white;
        background: #f2f3f7;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 8em;
        font-size: 1rem;
        transition-property: background-color, box-shadow;
        transition-duration: .2s;
        color: #7b7e8c;
    }

    #modal-link-close {
        box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -6px -6px 10px white;
        background: #f2f3f7;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 8em;
        font-size: 1rem;
        transition-property: background-color, box-shadow;
        transition-duration: .2s;
        color: #7b7e8c;
    }

    #modal-link-close:active {
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 transparent, 0 0 transparent, inset 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset -3px -3px 5px white;
        background: #f8f9fb;

        transition-duration: .1s;
    }

    button:active,
    select {
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 transparent, 0 0 transparent, inset 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset -3px -3px 5px white;
        background: #f8f9fb;
        transition-duration: .1s;
    }

    select {
        appearance: none;
        background: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: right;
        background-size: 1.8em;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding-right: 3em;
    }

    .lightgreen {
        color: lightgreen;
    }

    .red {
        color: red
    }

    .border-round {
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .box-shadow {
        box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -6px -6px 10px white;
    }

    .modal {
        padding: 10px 20px 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        min-height: 100px;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        background: #f2f3f7;
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    #svg {
        z-index: 0;
    }

    .canvas {
        position: absolute;
    }

    .node {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .node:hover {
        stroke: red
    }

    .link {
        fill: none;
        cursor: default;
        stroke: red;
        stroke-width: 3px;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <section id="modal-link" class="modal box-shadow">
        <h5 style="text-align:center">Relationship</h5>
        <hr class="border-round">
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <label id="details-link-source">Source --- </label>
            <select id="details-link-type-selection">
                <option>option 1</option>
                <option>option 2</option>
            </select>
            <label id="details-link-target"> --- Target</label>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <button id="modal-link-save" class="border-round"><i class="fas fa-check-circle lightgreen"></i>
                Save</button>
            <button id="modal-link-close" class="border-round"><i class="fas fa-times-circle red"></i>
                Close</button></button>
        </div>
    </section>

    <svg id="svg" width="100%"> </svg>

    <script>
        var graph = {
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                }
            ],
            "links": [
                {
                    "source": 1,
                    "target": 0,
                },
                {
                    "source": 2,
                    "target": 0,
                },
            ]
        }

        var width = window.innerWidth
        var height = window.innerHeight
        var isVisible = false;

        var svg = d3.select("svg")
            .attr("class", "canvas")
            .attr("height", height)
            .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
                svg.attr("transform", event.transform)
            }))
            .append("g")

        var modalLinkWindow = document.getElementById("modal-link")
        modalLinkWindow.style.display = "none"


        // remove zoom on dblclick listener
        d3.select("svg").on("dblclick.zoom", null)

        var linkContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "linkContainer")
        var nodeContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodeContainer")

        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
                return d.id;
            }).distance(150))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-50))
            .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
            .force("collision", d3.forceCollide().radius(30))


        //###############################################
        //############## Initialization #################
        //###############################################

        initialize()

        function initialize() {

            link = linkContainer.selectAll(".link")
                .data(graph.links)
                .join("line")
                .attr("class", "link")

            var grads = svg.append("defs").selectAll("radialGradient")
                .data(graph.nodes)
                .join("radialGradient")
                .attr("gradientUnits", "objectBoundingBox")
                .attr("cx", 0)
                .attr("cy", 0)
                .attr("r", "100%")
                .attr("id", function (d, i) { return "grad" + i; });

            grads.append("stop")
                .attr("offset", "80%")
                .style("stop-color", "whitesmoke");

            grads.append("stop")
                .attr("offset", "100%")
                .style("stop-color", "darkgrey");

            node = nodeContainer.selectAll(".node")
                .data(graph.nodes, d => d.id)
                .join("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragStarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragEnded)
                )
                .on("click", function () {
                    if (!isVisible) {
                        modalLinkWindow.style.display = "block"
                        isVisible = true
                    } else {
                        modalLinkWindow.style.display = "none"
                        isVisible = false
                    }
                })

            node.selectAll("circle")
                .data(d => [d])
                .join("circle")
                .attr("r", 30)
                //.style("fill", "white")
                .style("fill", function (d, i) {
                    return "url(#grad" + i + ")"
                })

            node.selectAll("text")
                .data(d => [d])
                .join("text")
                .style("class", "icon")
                .attr("font-family", "FontAwesome")
                .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("font-size", 30)
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .attr("stroke-width", "0px")
                .attr("pointer-events", "none")
                .text((d) => {
                    return d.id
                })

            simulation
                .nodes(graph.nodes)
                .on("tick", ticked);

            simulation
                .force("link")
                .links(graph.links)
        }


        //###############################################
        //############# Update Positions ################
        //###############################################

        function ticked() {
            // update link positions
            link
                .attr("x1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.x;
                })
                .attr("y1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.y;
                })
                .attr("x2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.x;
                })
                .attr("y2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.y;
                });

            // update node positions
            node
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";
                });
        }

        //###############################################
        //################ Drag Nodes ###################
        //###############################################

        function dragStarted(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;
        }

        function dragged(event, d) {
            d.fx = event.x;
            d.fy = event.y;
        }

        function dragEnded(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
            d.fx = undefined;
            d.fy = undefined;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```